# Using view makes query real slow but using equivalent SQL makes query real fast

Tags: postgresql

I have a view `client_order_histories` and we do some more querying on the view joining other tables:

View definition:

```
CREATE VIEW client_order_histories AS
 WITH references_with_custom AS (
         SELECT external_references.order_id,
            external_references.reference,
            company_custom_references.label,
            company_custom_references.type,
            company_custom_references.priority
           FROM (external_references
             LEFT JOIN company_custom_references ON ((company_custom_references.id = external_references.company_custom_reference_id)))
        )
 SELECT o.id,
    o.guid,
    to_char(timezone((d.time_zone)::text, timezone('utc'::text, o.delivered_at)), 'FMMonth DD, YYYY'::text) AS delivered_at,
    COALESCE(references_as_json."references", '[{"type": null, "label": null, "priority": null, "reference": null}]'::jsonb) AS external_ref,
    p.time_zone AS pickup_tz,
    o.company_id,
    o.status AS order_status,
    concat_ws(' '::text, p.company, p.street, p.street2, p.city, p.state, p.zip) AS pickup,
    concat_ws(' '::text, d.company, d.street, d.street2, d.city, d.state, d.zip) AS delivery
   FROM (((orders o
     LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('reference', references_with_custom.reference, 'label', references_with_custom.label, 'type', references_with_custom.type, 'priority', references_with_custom.priority)) AS "references"
           FROM references_with_custom
          WHERE (references_with_custom.order_id = o.id)) references_as_json ON (true))
     LEFT JOIN addresses p ON ((o.pickup_address_id = p.id)))
     LEFT JOIN addresses d ON ((o.delivery_address_id = d.id)))
  WHERE (o.status = ANY (ARRAY[6, 14, 15, 11]));
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE

SELECT "client_order_histories"."id",
       "client_order_histories"."company_id",
       "client_order_histories"."guid",
       "client_order_histories"."delivered_at",
       "client_order_histories"."pickup_tz",
       "client_order_histories"."pickup",
       "client_order_histories"."delivery",
       "client_order_histories"."external_ref",
       companies.name AS company_name
FROM "client_order_histories"
         LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = client_order_histories.company_id
WHERE "client_order_histories"."company_id" IN
      (1, 2, 3)
ORDER BY client_order_histories.id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

This is taking a long time and cost goes through the roof:

```
Limit  (cost=2068585.31..2068585.32 rows=20 width=190) (actual time=53715.040..53874.082 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2068585.31..2068624.20 rows=77778 width=190) (actual time=49832.477..49991.516 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: o.id DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 93kB
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2500.69..2068171.38 rows=77778 width=190) (actual time=33.403..49786.141 rows=82731 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2500.64..2063017.77 rows=77778 width=200) (actual time=33.383..48691.971 rows=82731 loops=1)
                    ->  Gather  (cost=2477.33..249783.12 rows=77778 width=209) (actual time=33.278..13517.121 rows=82731 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 1
                          Workers Launched: 1
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1477.33..241005.32 rows=45752 width=209) (actual time=587.304..21047.030 rows=41366 loops=2)
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1477.25..140146.10 rows=45752 width=126) (actual time=587.291..16115.761 rows=41366 loops=2)
                                      ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on orders o  (cost=1477.16..39286.88 rows=45752 width=43) (actual time=587.198..700.536 rows=41366 loops=2)
"                                            Recheck Cond: (company_id = ANY ('{779,157,597,321,506,780,343,656,856,967,979,1080,1125,1257,1471,1764}'::integer[]))"
"                                            Filter: (status = ANY ('{6,14,15,11}'::integer[]))"
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 28
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=6069
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_orders_on_company_id  (cost=0.00..1473.27 rows=82602 width=0) (actual time=25.727..25.727 rows=101830 loops=1)
"                                                  Index Cond: (company_id = ANY ('{779,157,597,321,506,780,343,656,856,967,979,1080,1125,1257,1471,1764}'::integer[]))"
                                      ->  Index Scan using addresses_pkey on addresses p  (cost=0.09..2.20 rows=1 width=95) (actual time=0.372..0.372 rows=1 loops=82731)
                                            Index Cond: (id = o.pickup_address_id)
                                ->  Index Scan using addresses_pkey on addresses d  (cost=0.09..2.20 rows=1 width=95) (actual time=0.118..0.118 rows=1 loops=82731)
                                      Index Cond: (id = o.delivery_address_id)
                    ->  Aggregate  (cost=23.30..23.30 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.409..0.409 rows=1 loops=82731)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.14..23.30 rows=5 width=70) (actual time=0.189..0.251 rows=9 loops=82731)
                                ->  Index Scan using index_external_references_on_order_id on external_references  (cost=0.09..4.99 rows=5 width=21) (actual time=0.181..0.217 rows=9 loops=82731)
                                      Index Cond: (order_id = o.id)
                                ->  Index Scan using company_custom_references_pkey on company_custom_references  (cost=0.06..3.66 rows=1 width=65) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=758125)
                                      Index Cond: (id = external_references.company_custom_reference_id)
              ->  Index Scan using companies_pkey on companies  (cost=0.06..0.06 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=82731)
                    Index Cond: (id = o.company_id)
Planning Time: 2.203 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 56
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 56.929 ms, Inlining 399.865 ms, Optimization 3906.047 ms, Emission 716.940 ms, Total 5079.782 ms
Execution Time: 53874.082 ms
```

But if I define the query for view as a CTE and use the CTE in the query, it is like so much faster:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE

WITH references_with_custom as (SELECT external_references.order_id,
                                       external_references.reference,
                                       company_custom_references.label,
                                       company_custom_references.type,
                                       company_custom_references.priority
                                FROM external_references
                                         LEFT JOIN company_custom_references on company_custom_references.id =
                                                                                   external_references.company_custom_reference_id),
     client_order_histories as (SELECT o.id,
                                       o.guid,
                                       to_char((o.delivered_at AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE d.time_zone),
                                               'FMMonth DD, YYYY'::text)                                      AS delivered_at,
                                       coalesce(references_as_json.references, '[
                                         {
                                           "reference": null,
                                           "label": null,
                                           "type": null,
                                           "priority": null
                                         }
                                       ]'::jsonb)                                                             as external_ref,
                                       p.time_zone                                                            as pickup_tz,
                                       o.company_id                                                           AS company_id,
                                       o.status                                                               AS order_status,
                                       concat_ws(' ', p.company, p.street, p.street2, p.city, p.state, p.zip) AS pickup,
                                       concat_ws(' ', d.company, d.street, d.street2, d.city, d.state,
                                                 d.zip)                                                       AS delivery
                                FROM orders o
                                         LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('reference',
                                                                                                references_with_custom.reference,
                                                                                                'label',
                                                                                                references_with_custom.label,
                                                                                                'type',
                                                                                                references_with_custom.type,
                                                                                                'priority',
                                                                                                references_with_custom.priority)) AS references
                                                            FROM references_with_custom
                                                            where references_with_custom.order_id = o.id) AS references_as_json
                                                   ON TRUE
                                         LEFT JOIN addresses p ON o.pickup_address_id = p.id
                                         LEFT JOIN addresses d ON o.delivery_address_id = d.id
                                WHERE o.status IN (6, 14, 15, 11))
                                
    SELECT "client_order_histories"."id",
           "client_order_histories"."company_id",
           "client_order_histories"."guid",
           "client_order_histories"."delivered_at",
           "client_order_histories"."pickup_tz",
           "client_order_histories"."pickup",
           "client_order_histories"."delivery",
           "client_order_histories"."external_ref",
           companies.name as company_name
    FROM "client_order_histories"
             LEFT join companies on companies.id = client_order_histories.company_id
    WHERE "client_order_histories"."company_id" IN
          (779, 157, 597, 321, 506, 780, 343, 656, 856, 967, 979, 1080, 1125, 1257, 1471, 1745)
    order by client_order_histories.id desc
    limit 20
```

```
Limit  (cost=23.61..600.95 rows=20 width=190) (actual time=1.922..4.449 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=23.61..2245209.39 rows=77778 width=190) (actual time=1.921..4.443 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=23.56..2240094.67 rows=77778 width=241) (actual time=1.886..4.259 rows=20 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=23.47..2068634.87 rows=77778 width=158) (actual time=1.877..4.150 rows=20 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=23.39..1897175.07 rows=77778 width=75) (actual time=1.861..3.998 rows=20 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan using order_id_desc on orders o  (cost=0.08..84134.87 rows=77778 width=43) (actual time=1.687..1.928 rows=20 loops=1)
"                                Filter: ((status = ANY ('{6,14,15,11}'::integer[])) AND (company_id = ANY ('{779,157,597,321,506,780,343,656,856,967,979,1080,1125,1257,1471,1745}'::integer[])))"
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1052
                          ->  Aggregate  (cost=23.30..23.30 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.102..0.102 rows=1 loops=20)
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.14..23.30 rows=5 width=70) (actual time=0.011..0.028 rows=10 loops=20)
                                      ->  Index Scan using index_external_references_on_order_id on external_references  (cost=0.09..4.99 rows=5 width=21) (actual time=0.007..0.013 rows=10 loops=20)
                                            Index Cond: (order_id = o.id)
                                      ->  Index Scan using company_custom_references_pkey on company_custom_references  (cost=0.06..3.66 rows=1 width=65) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=208)
                                            Index Cond: (id = external_references.company_custom_reference_id)
                    ->  Index Scan using addresses_pkey on addresses p  (cost=0.09..2.20 rows=1 width=95) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=20)
                          Index Cond: (id = o.pickup_address_id)
              ->  Index Scan using addresses_pkey on addresses d  (cost=0.09..2.20 rows=1 width=95) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=20)
                    Index Cond: (id = o.delivery_address_id)
        ->  Index Scan using companies_pkey on companies  (cost=0.06..0.06 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=20)
              Index Cond: (id = o.company_id)
Planning Time: 2.427 ms
Execution Time: 4.579 ms
```

and I dont see the sort part in the analyse. Is there a way to force the view to use the same query plan as the inline query with CTE

Comment: Postgres is materializing the CTE as far as I know, which might explain the difference in performance.  Note that a CTE and a view are 2 different things.

Comment: I tried using CTE inside the view, and doing `Select * from ` the CTE, but it also was really expensive

Comment: CTE != view ... please fix your terminology

Comment: Try moving `ORDER BY client_order_histories.id DESC LIMIT 20` outside the CTE

Comment: I don't think we will get very far without seeing the view/CTE. definition

Comment: I will add those, probably will remove later @jjanes

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  No, it is inlining the CTE.  If it were materializing it, there would be a node in the plan for it.

Comment: @jjanes updated the queries with view definition and CTE

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @jjanes 12.9 version

Comment: @jjanes is there a way to keep the sql query with CTE like sit like a query, so that I can call client_orders_history as the CTE instead of the view